# Runtime error imacros script blocking y loop

Tags: scripting, runtime-error, tumblr, imacros

Using Imacros on tumblr I'm getting this error each time the save button has been pressed

```
RuntimeError: Error loading page about:blank, line 7 (Error code: -933)
```

This is the imacros script

```
TAB T=1 
TAG POS=1 TYPE=I ATTR=CLASS:icon_post_photo&&TXT:
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE FORM=ID:edit_post ATTR=NAME:images[o1] CONTENT=C:\sampleimage.jpg
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Set<SP>a<SP>click-through<SP>link
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:edit_post ATTR=ID:post_three CONTENT=http://www.website.com/
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ID:edit_post ATTR=ID:post_state CONTENT=%2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:edit_post ATTR=ID:save_button
```

the post get posted but it stops my loop.
Anyone got an idea on what could it possibly be?

Comment: Can you format code properly.

Comment: I tried formatting it by adding 4 spaces as stated in the FAQ but it doesn't work! However I resolved just by adding SET !ERRORIGNORE YES